# create dynamic navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a navigation bar with read the values from xml file and display menu and submenu from it.

Here the html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <title>Try Menu</title>
     <link href="Stylesheet/StyleSheetNav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
     <script src="Script/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
     <script src="Script/JScriptMenu.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div id="messages">
     <script src="Script/JScriptMenuHover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

this is my xml file XMLNav.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
     <Menu>
     <nav>
     <mainmenu>
         <name>Home</name>
         <link>#</link>
         <submenu>
             <text>Pro</text>
         </submenu>
         <submenu>
             <text>Educ</text>
         </submenu>
    </mainmenu>
    <mainmenu>
         <name>Products</name>
         <link>#</link>
         <submenu>
             <text>EduCube</text>
         </submenu>
         <submenu>
              <text>web Solu</text>
         </submenu>
    </mainmenu>
    <mainmenu>
        <name>Services</name>
        <link>#</link>
        <submenu>
            <text>Web</text>
        </submenu>
        <submenu>
             <text>cloud</text>
        </submenu>
        <submenu>
              <text>Mobile</text>
        </submenu>
    </mainmenu>
    <mainmenu>
        <name>About Us</name>
        <link>#</link>
        <submenu/>
    </mainmenu>
</nav>
</Menu>
```

this is my js file JScriptMenu.js:

```
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "XMLNav.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("mainmenu");
        var len = x.length;
        var y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("submenu");

        document.write("<div><nav id='mainNav'><ul id='main-menu-ul'>");

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            document.write("<li class='main-menu'><a href='#'>");
            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            document.write("</a>");
            var z = y[i].childNodes;
            if (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("submenu").length != 0) {
                document.write("<div><ul class='sub-menu' ");
                for (j = 0; j < z.length; j++) {
                    document.write("<li><a href='#'>");
                    document.write(y[j].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                    document.write("</a></li>");
                }
                document.write("</ul></div>");
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
            document.write("</li>");
        }
        document.write("</ul></nav></div>");
```

this is menu hovering file JScriptMenuHover.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.main-menu').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').fadeIn('fast');
        $(this).css('background-color', '#99CA46');
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').fadeOut('fast');
        $(this).css('background-color', '#434343');
    });
});
```

this the main menu is getting printed well but only 1st 3 submenu are coming in every menu.

whenever i am hovering my mouse on 1st item for my main menu it displays the 1st three sub menu only. its reading 1st three submenu only for all the menu item.
is their a problem in js file or xml file is not proper?

I want my menu to be like this,

```
*Home
    ->Pro
    ->Educ
*Products
    ->cloud
    ->Web
```

etc..

Please help.

Comment: "is their a problem in js file or xml file is not proper?" How should we know? You tell us. Does it work?

Comment: its reading 1st three submenu from xml file. not particular submenu.. for all elements just 1st three.... 
http://prntscr.com/7nhdkd
see the image... it should be like Product -> EduCube -> Web Sol...